# 2d arrays and sizes in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, size, 2d

I'm sure it's something very trivial, but I fail to understand it,

```
int  bb5[8][8]
 = {
                {-4,-3,-2,-5,-6,-2,-3,-4},
                {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                { 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4}
                };
```

This works

```
int bb5[7][7]
 = {
                {-4,-3,-2,-5,-6,-2,-3,-4},
                {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                { 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4}
                };
```

This doesn't work, "too many initializers for `int[7][7]`
I'm using this data structure in a chess engine that I built from scratch for fun. This array is displayed graphically in the screen, a chess board is 8x8, so I thought `int  bb5[7][7]` is the equivalent (from 0 to 7 `==` size 8 right? ), but I am doing it wrong, why?

Comment: Indices go from `0` - `7`, size must be `8`.

Comment: When you declare an array in the size of 7, it's from 0 to 6.

Comment: when you declare `int a[7];` `7` is not the last valid index, it is the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The value inside the `[]` in an array is the **size** of the array. Indexing of numbers begins with `0` though, hence the maximum index you can access in an array is `size - 1`.